# Has the United States paid US dollars as reparations to children other than a "child" of Japanese American internees during World War II?

Tags: united-states, law

Has the United States officially paid reparations in the form of US dollars to any parties that were a "child"

["Civil Liberties Act of 1988" (PUBLIC LAW 100-383—AUG. 10,1988; Public Law 100-383, 100th Congress; 102 Stat. 903. Public Section 105. Restitution. (a)(7)(C)(ii))](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/STATUTE-102/pdf/STATUTE-102-Pg903.pdf)

> a "child" of an eligible individual includes a recognized natural
>   child, a stepchild who lived with the eligible individual in a regular
>   parent-child relationship, and an adopted child

other than the children of an eligible individual who suffered

> the fundamental injustice of the evacuation, relocation, and
>   internment of United States citizens and permanent resident aliens of
>   Japanese ancestry during World War II

?

Comment: The referenced act also allows for payments to Aleuts, who were transferred from their homes "for safe keeping".  Payments for damages have occurred since the American Revolutionary War; consider the "Fire Lands", established in the "Western Reserve" of Ohio, for people burned out of their homes in Connecticut by the British.

Comment: Are you asking whether anyone under 18 has been given reparations? Whether anyone has been given reparations on the basis of what happened to their parents, other than regarding Japanese internment? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @Acccumulation Has the definition of "child" in the cited act been applied to any affected party _other than_ the "eligible" Japanese defined in the law where the U.S. directly paid US dollars as reparations (legal or war) to that "child"; e.g., "stepchild", "adopted child"; has the letter of the law as to "child" been applied to other individuals or groups that _were not_ Japanese internees, relocatees, evacuatees during World War II?

Comment: @PeterDiehr How are the "Fire Lands" related to reparations?

Comment: @guest271314: they were payments, in the form of land grants, for losses suffered during the war.  Reparations: "the making of amends for a wrong one has done, by paying money to or otherwise helping those who have been wronged."  In this case, the latter sense.

Comment: @PeterDiehr The law specifically authorizes US dollars to be paid to the affected party. Am trying to determine if actual US dollars have been paid to any other individual, not land grants or other forms of compensation. And if there are any other instances of federal laws which made the "child", "stepchild" or "adopted child" of an eligible party also eligible to receive those US dollars.

Comment: @PeterDiehr If your estimation is that your comments answers the question, can you post an answer detailing your reasoning?

Comment: @guest271314: the question requires clarification, per the comments above, before anyone can offer an answer. Specifically, the scope is unclear wrt the time period(s) in question; and any limitations on the people involved.

Comment: @PeterDiehr Relevant to land found [William T. Sherman's Special Field Order No. 15](http://www.freedmen.umd.edu/sfo15.htm), have yet to locate Major General John G. Foster's General Orders No. 8, or the actual document (and, if available, _reasons_) where President Andrew Johnson made Sherman's Special Field Order No. 15 null and void; see [What are the primary source records which document the reasons for President Andrew Johnson's voiding of Sherman’s Special Field Order No. 15?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/33326/). Am currently banned from asking questions at History SE.

Comment: Please edit all clarifications into the question; comments get deleted.  Comments ask for clarification, and the question should be edited to clarify the issue.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace How do you suggest editing the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Firelands was part of the Western Reserve of Connecticut in the Northwest Territory.](http://www.ohiohistorycentral.org/w/Firelands) This area is now part of Ohio, and it was reserved specifically for people burned out of their homes in Connecticut by the British during the Revolutionary War.

This is an example of early reparations, authorized by US law.